# Start Netflix Android App

Tags: android, netflix

I'm looking for a way to start the Netflix application and for it to go to a particular movie on Android.  I have the full URL and I can even get the movie id, but I'm not sure how to start the Netflix app and give it this info.

For iOS apps there's the "nflx://www.netflix.com" URL Scheme.  Anyone done something similar for Android apps?

Comment: Please refer to my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217559/launching-android-netflix-app-and-passing-video-id/34486210#34486210):

Comment: I've managed to do this, [please refer to this response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217559/launching-android-netflix-app-and-passing-video-id/34486210#34486210).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the Netflix clients support a variety of action-based URLs such as:
www.netflix.com/watch/videoId (e.g. [www.netflix.com/watch/70300800](http://www.netflix.com/watch/70300800))
www.netflix.com/title/videoId (e.g. [www.netflix.com/title/70300800](http://www.netflix.com/title/70300800))

Support for these links is provided in the Android application.

However this is not an official or public spec and thus is subject to change.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
nflx://www.netflix.com/WiPlayer?movieid=___trkid=___&episodeid=___
```

But be aware that Netflix doesn't actually support external launch points as one developer said (http://developer.netflix.com/forum/read/70098):

> At this point, we aren't officially supporting any external launch
>   points into the Netflix iPad application. If you suss them out
>   yourselves and use them, the danger is that they may eventually go
>   away.

Comment: That url does not currently work with netflix on an android device :(