# Launching a netflix movie from chromecast sender app

Tags: netflix, chromecast

I'm working on a chromecast sender application where I would like to have netflix launch and play the requested movie. However, I can only manage to launch the Netflix application, but it doesn't load the video as I am not sure which parameters I need to send with the request.

I've been unable to find any resources where Netflix discusses this. Is this possible? Or will netflix only launch and play videos from requests made within it's own application?

Comment: Can you share the appId of Netflix?
I have found YouTube 233637DE and Media Player CC1AD845 but I am missing Netflix

Answer (score 3):

This isn't supported on Chromecast.  Nor is it expected to be in the future.

Instead, you could ask Netflix to play a movie through Intents on Android, and through the right URI on iOS as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910321/start-netflix-android-app).

Comment: This answer could use a more elaboration on what data Android intents need when being used to start Netflix.