# Launching Android Netflix App And Passing Video Id

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, netflix

In the app I am working on I want to support Netfilx streaming. I intend on doing this by simply starting Netflix and passing a specific URI so it plays a specific video when started. Simple right? Well, the issue is I'm not sure how to pass the video id info in the Intent I use to start the Activity.

I've read the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10910321/start-netflix-android-app) , but am unsure where to use this. I used Intent.setData() since it accepts a URI, but to no avail.

Here is what I have been doing (I am hard coding the movie data, this is just for testing purposes) :

```
// the Netflix intent
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.netflix.mediaclient");
//the uri
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://movies.netflix.com/WiPlayer?movieid=70266228&trkid=13462049&ctx=0%2C1%2Ce2bd7b74-6743-4d5e-864f-1cc2568ba0da-61921755");
intent.setData(uri);
//launches but does not go to the video
startActivity(intent);
```

I've also tried using the URI protocol in the link above like so:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("nflx://movies.netflix.com/WiPlayer?movieid=70266228&trkid=13462049&ctx=0%2C1%2Ce2bd7b74-6743-4d5e-864f-1cc2568ba0da-61921755");
```

but still am not seeing the video play.

I feel like I am missing something simple here, although I have had very little luck Googling for this, I could find next to nothing about starting the Netflix Android app from another application. The Netflix developer resources don't have any info on this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this or where I should be looking for documentation on this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks much!

Comment: according to the commenter in your link, he says that this does not work in android. whats the point of launching the netflix app to play a video anyway?

Comment: @tyczj - because it's a business requirement for the app.... that's why I want to launch Netflix.

Comment: well does your business realize that this is an undocumented intent that might not even work now or in the future?

Comment: @tyczi - yes, they are aware, I've advised against it, and have been told to do everything I can to get this to work. So, here I am.

Comment: Hi, I am interested in the same feature. Did you make it work?

Comment: @Sim - no, the decision was made to not try and do this as it could not be done reliably

Answer (score 8):

Just some Android Apps intent names to help anyone.

Format: **appName**, **packageName**, **className**

Skype: `com.skype.raider`, `com.skype.raider.Main`

Netflix: `com.netflix.mediaclient`, `com.netflix.mediaclient.ui.launch.UIWebViewActivity`

ESexplorer: `com.estrongs.android.pop`, `com.estrongs.android.pop.view.FileExplorerActivity`

Youtube: `com.google.android.youtube`,`com.google.android.youtube.HomeActivity`

Chrome: `com.android.chrome`,`com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main`

VLC: `org.videolan.vlc`, `org.videolan.vlc.gui.MainActivity`

MBOXSettings: `com.mbx.settingsmbox`, `com.mbx.settingsmbox.SettingsMboxActivity`

Answer (score 7):

I've managed to do this. With the following code. First you need the movieId (or videoId) for netflix, then compose the URL to watch.

```
String netFlixId = "43598743"; // <== isn't a real movie id
String watchUrl = "http://www.netflix.com/watch/"+netFlixId;
```

Then with this intent

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClassName("com.netflix.mediaclient", "com.netflix.mediaclient.ui.launch.UIWebViewActivity");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(watchUrl));
        startActivity(intent);            
}
catch(Exception e)
{
        // netflix app isn't installed, send to website.
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(item.url));
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

I haven't tried with TV Shows yet. But this works beautifully. If you want to send to the **profile page** of the movie.. Send it to a url formatted this way

```
http://www.netflix.com/title/324982
```

I also found out how to **search for a title**.

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        intent.setClassName("com.netflix.mediaclient", "com.netflix.mediaclient.ui.search.SearchActivity");
        intent.putExtra("query", item.label);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install the NetFlix App!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to start a movie from an ADB command for **com.netflix.mediaclient**

```
adb shell am start -n com.netflix.mediaclient/.ui.launch.UIWebViewActivity -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.netflix.com/watch/60000724
```

I still can't find a way to do it for com.netflix.ninja (Netflix for Android TV)

Comment: you need to use action android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW for com.netflix.ninja version